# embed youtube video not autoplaying with sound in iphone

Tags: javascript, ios, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I have integrated a youtube video in my website in auto-play mode with sound. It is working perfectly on android phones, but not on iPhones. If I enable volume then the auto-play function is not working. The auto-play is working only when the video is muted on iPhone. This is my code.

```html
<iframe
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/baGSq10ma0I?enablejsapi=1&amp;playsinline=1&mute=&autoplay=1"
    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
    allowfullscreen=""
    width="100%"
    height="300"
    frameborder="0"
></iframe>
```

Comment: where is the code

Comment: <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/baGSq10ma0I?enablejsapi=1&amp;playsinline=1&amp;mute=&amp;autoplay=1&amp;mute=1&amp;playsinline=1" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" width="100%" height="300" frameborder="0"></iframe>

Comment: remove the. mute key and check

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik If I remove mute key then video will not auto-play in iphone.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest please checkout YouTube Player for iOS, you can then embed it in any view
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper